# Getting InputMismatchException When Reading Text File into Integer Array

Tags: java, arrays, file-io, integer

I am reading a text file filled with numbers (on individual lines) into an integer array. I thought I wrote the program well but am having issues when I try to run it. Netbeans is telling me "InputMismatchException."  I think the problem is located in my second method called readTxtFile specifically the while loop. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
package arrayspa;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class ArraysPA {

/**
 * Using the enrollment.txt file, count and display the number of full
 * sections and the percentage of the sections that are full. A section is
 * full if it contains 36 students.
 */
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception 
{
    //an array to hold total # of students in each section
    int[] numStud = new int[100];
    int count; //number of elements actually used
    int fullSections; //number of full sections (36 enrolled students)
    int percent; //percentage of sections that are full

    //read data into numStud[] from txt file
    count = readTxtFile(numStud);

    //print the array on the screen
    System.out.println("The original file:");
    displayLines(numStud,count);

    //calculate number of sections that are full and display number
    fullSections = calcFullSections(numStud, count);
    System.out.println("There are "+fullSections+ "full sections.");

    //display percentage of sections that are full
    percent = fullSections/count;
    System.out.println("The percentage of sections that are full is " 
            +percent);

} //end main()

/**
 * This methods read data from enrollment.txt (located in project folder)
 * line by line into an integer array. It then uses an if statement to 
 * display the total number of full sections (a section is considered full
 * if there are 36 students enrolled).
 */
public static int readTxtFile(int[] numStud) throws Exception
{
    int i=0; //number of elements in array initialized to zero

    //Create File class object linked to enrollment.txt
    java.io.File enrollment = new java.io.File("enrollment.txt");

    //Create a Scanner named infile to read input stream from file
    Scanner infile = new Scanner(enrollment);

    /**Create while loop to read lines of text into array. It uses the
     *Scanner class boolean function hasNextLine() to see if there is
     *another line in the file.
     */ 
    while (infile.hasNextLine())
    {
        //read a line and put it in an array element
        numStud[i] = infile.nextInt();
        i ++; //increment the number of array elements
    } //end while

    infile.close();
    return i; //returns number of items used in the array
} //end readTxtFile(int[] numStud

public static void displayLines(int[] lines, int count)
{
    int i; //loop counter

    // iterate the elements actually used
    for (i=0; i < count; i++)
        System.out.println(lines[i]);
} //end displayLines()

public static int calcFullSections(int[] numStud, int count)
{
    int fullSections=0; //number of full sections
    int i;            //loop counter

    for (i=0; i < count; i++)
        if (numStud[i]==36)
        {
            fullSections = fullSections + 1;
        }

    return fullSections;   
} //end calcFullSections()
```

}

Comment: I think, you might have an empty line at the end of the input file, which can not convert to `int`, hence throwing the exception. Remove any empty lines from the file or you read them as strings and check if they are blanks or remove any trailing spaces and then do an `Integer.parseInt()`

Answer (score 0):

An `InputMismatchException` is thrown when input does not match the type of variable you are writing to. I have tested your code and it seemed to work fine unless the file "enrollment.txt" has a blank line or spaces. I have tested adding a blank line to the end of the file and running it, and I received a `NoSuchElementException`, so the problem is probably a blank line or non-integer somewhere in your file. To fix this, you can either remove any blank lines/non-integers in your file, or, preferably, you can modify your `readTxtFile()` method to ignore blank lines by catching a `NoSuchElementException`, like so:

```
public static int readTxtFile(int[] numStud) throws Exception
{
int i=0; //number of elements in array initialized to zero

//Create File class object linked to enrollment.txt
java.io.File enrollment = new java.io.File("enrollment.txt");

//Create a Scanner named infile to read input stream from file
Scanner infile = new Scanner(enrollment);

/**Create while loop to read lines of text into array. It uses the
 *Scanner class boolean function hasNextLine() to see if there is
 *another line in the file.
 */ 
while (infile.hasNextLine())
{
    // Add this try/catch block to prevent reading blank line
    try {
        numStud[i] = infile.nextInt();
        i ++; 
    } catch (NoSuchElementException e) {
    }
} //end while

infile.close();
return i; //returns number of items used in the array
} //end readTxtFile(int[] numStud
```

As you can see, I have added a try/catch block into your `readTxtFile()` void that catches a `NoSuchElementException`, which includes `InputMismatchException`, preventing an attempt to add in any non-integers. I hope this solves your problem!